# Изменение цвета шрифта в редакторе Eclipse

Tags: pydev, eclipse

Как можно в Eclipse изменить цвет шрифта в редакторе? Более конкретно - цвет комментариев в PyDev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В меню Windows -> Preference -> PyDev -> Editor, на этой странице в списке Appearance color options выбрать Comments и поменять цвет нажав на кнопку с текущим цветом.

Comment: а если нет в списке PyDev но он точно стоит, прям железно, ибо я с ним пишу и он уже настроеный